# How can I fetch inserted IDs from same flow which inserted new records?

Tags: visual-workflow

I am inserting ContentNote records then want to create ContentDocumentLink records with referring to the same ContentNote collection I inserted in the same flow.

I am trying to access the IDs of the inserted collection of ContentNote, but it's returning "true" value.

[image: ScreenShot0]
[image: Screenshot1]

How can I fetch the IDs which I inserted as a collection in the same flow?

Edit: I think I got a step forward : I was using {!Insert_Note_collection} which is component's api name rather than the variable of collection which I am using in "Add CN to collection" component i.e., {!varContentNoteCollection}

Using the variable {!varContentNoteCollection} , now I'm getting the inserted Id.

Now I the question is to access those records using collection variable which is not working in "Get records"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question properly, and you need to access the records whose Ids are in that collection variable, you would need to do the following:

1. Get Records element
2. Set criteria to Id, set the operator to "In" and set the value to your collection variable {!varContentNoteCollection}

That should return all the records if their Id is the collection